# What is m through n instances of preceding element in MySql?

Tags: mysql, regex

I am not getting the {m, n} syntax of MySql. What is it? How this is used in queries? 
I am writing queries on Like statements and regex statements.
This is my query:

```
select 
    distinct city 
from 
    station
where 
    city regexp 'a{m, n}';
```

Just ignore the query. Just tell me how this is used. Added query to fool the Stack Overflow. It is always saying to add code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn’t (really) about MySql. It is about regular expressions. `a{m,n}` means between m and n times the letter `a` Consequtively.

So, for example, with `where mycolumn regexp 'doh{3,5}'` you will match all rows where mycolumn contains `dohhh`, `dohhhh` or `dohhhhh`.

See also https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/oracle-regular-expressions/0596006012/re13.html

Comment: note `a{m, n}` with space in between will not work, it should be `a{m,n}`

Answer (score 0):

you almost got the correct query

> {m,n} -> The preceding element or subexpression must occur between m and
>   n times, inclusive.

So below query, you are trying to get rows with column with `'a'` between min and max

```
select 
    distinct city 
from 
    station
where 
    city regexp 'a{1,3}';
```

Try [sqlfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=0Sa0p6cqT7)